# Error updating UI, setState() not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I have two buttons on flutter screen (`add to cart` and `remove from cart`).
`cartQuantity` is a variable I have declared in my `build()` method to keep a track of users cart quantity.

When the user presses the add button, the UI for `quantity x rate` should change which doesn't seem to happen.

The `Row` widget contains 'REMOVE' button, user's cart quantity and 'ADD' button respectively.

```
class ItemBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  final RestaurantItems restaurantItem;
  final Restaurant restaurant;
  const ItemBottomSheet({
    this.restaurantItem,
    this.restaurant,
  });

  @override
  _ItemBottomSheetState createState() => _ItemBottomSheetState();
}

class _ItemBottomSheetState extends State<ItemBottomSheet> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final cartItems = Provider.of<Cart>(context).getCartItems;
    final index = cartItems.indexWhere((cartItem) =>
        cartItem.id == widget.restaurantItem.id &&
        cartItem.restaurantId == widget.restaurant.id);
    int restQuantity = widget.restaurantItem.quantity;
    int cartQuantity = 0;
    if (index != -1) {
      cartQuantity = cartItems[index].quantity;
    }

    return Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: darkThemeColour,
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
              topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0))),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                    topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0))),
            height: size.height * 0.21,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20), topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
              child: Image.network(
                widget.restaurantItem.imageUrl,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              // SizedBox(
              //   height: 12,
              //   width: 12,
              //   child: SvgPicture.asset(
              //     'lib/assets/icons/green-circle.svg',
              //     color: restaurantItem.isVeg ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
              //   ),
              // ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, left: 18),
                child: Text(
                  widget.restaurantItem.name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                      fontSize: 21,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 17),
            child: Text(
              '₹${widget.restaurantItem.price}',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 27),
            child: Text(
              'Pickup Between',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
            child: Text(
              '${DateFormat.jm().format(widget.restaurant.pickupTime.start)}  -  ${DateFormat.jm().format(widget.restaurant.pickupTime.end)}',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                  fontSize: 17,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, left: 18),
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Material(
                    color: index == -1 ||
                            cartItems[index].quantity == 0 ||
                            widget.restaurantItem.quantity <= 1
                        ? Colors.grey
                        : Colors.green, // button color
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.white30, // inkwell color
                      child: SizedBox(
                          width: 60,
                          height: 60,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.remove,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 28,
                          )),
                      onTap: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: Text(
                  cartQuantity > 0
                      ? '$cartQuantity x ₹${widget.restaurantItem.price}'
                      : '₹${widget.restaurantItem.price}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, right: 18),
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Material(
                    color: widget.restaurantItem.quantity <= 1
                        ? Colors.grey
                        : Colors.green, // button color
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.white30, // inkwell color
                      child: SizedBox(
                          width: 56,
                          height: 56,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          cartQuantity++;
                          print(cartQuantity.toString());
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          FillButton(
            text: 'ADD TO CART',
            function: () {
              // setState(() {
              //   cartQuantity++;
              // });
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: Text(
              widget.restaurantItem.isVeg ? 'VEG' : 'NON - VEG',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                  fontSize: 17,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                  color:
                      widget.restaurantItem.isVeg ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: size.height * 0.3,
            color: darkThemeColour,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you declared and initialised cartQuantity in build method? this part of code does not help

Comment: You need to show all the widget so we can be able to see the issue

Comment: I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because in your build you are initialiazing your cartQuantity to 0 each time you do a rebuild of the widget. You should initialize it outside the build.

```
class _ItemBottomSheetState extends State<ItemBottomSheet> {

  int cartQuantity = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final cartItems = Provider.of<Cart>(context).getCartItems;
    final index = cartItems.indexWhere((cartItem) =>
        cartItem.id == widget.restaurantItem.id &&
        cartItem.restaurantId == widget.restaurant.id);
    int restQuantity = widget.restaurantItem.quantity;
```

Now your value will not be always 0 because you initialize it in the construction of the widget. Each time you call setState you do a rebuild and you build gets called.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that any value changed under setState() will not rebuild the entire widget and only the part of the widget where the value is relevant.